# How to 'drop' a POST request if it is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

How do you write a before filter that just ignores a request if it is deemed invalid?

The most simple design is checking if all the fields are present in the incoming request.  If one of them is not, I want the Rails app to return just enough info so I can test the validation.

Right now, I have a very simple idea:

```
class ListenerController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :requires_login, :requires_employee
  before_filter :validate
  protect_from_forgery except: :create

  def create
    render nothing: true
    Listener.process(params)
  end

  private

  def validate
    return_invalid unless params[:id].present?
    return_invalid unless params[:content].present?
    return_invalid unless params[:summary].present?
    return_invalid unless params[:displayName].present?
    true
  end

  def return_invalid
    #do something to return simple message
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: `render plain: 'Invalid'` Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a 400 status code.

```
def return_invalid
  head(400)
end
```

Rails will immediately return at the end of the filter and render the status code.

If you want something more user-friendly (example a message), then redirect to an action (either the same, or a "new") and pass a message as a `flash` message.

```
def return_invalid
  redirect_to { action: "new" }, alert: "Something is wrong"
end
```